# indentationRule doesn't work in vscode language-configuration.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a custom language extension for vscode. In the `language-configuration.json` file, I tried to specify the `indentationRules` like this:

```
"indentationRules": {
      "increaseIndentPattern": "^\\s*(if|elif|else|while).*$",
}
```

This is to supposed to support some Python-style indentations like:

```
if 3 > 2
      print(True)
```

However, the auto indentation never works.
The [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#indentation-rules) says that `increaseIndentPattern` is supposed to be a regex that matches the line before the indentation, which I think my regex does match the line `if 3 > 2`. What do I do  wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Try doing the simplest form, `"^if"` and see if that indents after an `if` at the start of the line. That should allow you to narrow it down to either your regex or a broken feature :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks. I have already tried that before posting this question but oddly it also doesn't work.

Comment: Then I would say it's not a regex problem. Next step would be to check (1) is this supported in the vscode version you're using; (2) is this config file being loaded correctly (eg, is it in the right place) or is some other file being used - maybe introduce an explicit error into your file to check that. Restarting vscode should then(hopefully) complain about the error. I know that's clutching at straws but you'd be surprised how many problems I've fixed with that method :-)

Comment: The reason why I think the regex is the problem is that the example regex "^((?!\\/\\/).)*(\\{[^}\"'`]*|\\([^)\"'`]*|\\[[^\\]\"'`]*)$" from the doc works. It matches lines like "if (3 > 2) {"

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you must have a `decreaseIndentPattern` rule. Otherwise the `increaseIndentPattern` rule is simply ignored (and the bracket-based indentation triggers).

I believe that `"decreaseIndentPattern": "^[^ ]$"` should be a noop.

Comment: Even after the above, I was not able.
Then found that I had a "editor.autoIndent": "none" in my settings.json file which was the problem.